# Why class definition is changed when reference added to C# project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, windows-7

I am working on C# on Win 7 Visual Studio 2012.

I have added a reference (defined and compiled in a .dll file in another location) to my C# project because I need to call a function that is defined in a class of that lib file.

But, when I check the definition from my current project, I find that the definition is changed and it is different from what I see when I open the source file where the class is defined.

I am new to C#.

What is the possible reason?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.Odbc;

namespace MyName
{
     public class MyDataLoad  // the class definition is changed when I call it !!!
     {
         #region
         // some functions definition
         #endregion

         void MyLoadDataFile()
         {

         }
     }
}
```

---

UPDATE AGAIN

The definition of MyLoadDataFile() noes not exist in the .cs file where class MyDataLoad is defined. I open the file by right-clicking MyLoadDataFile() in my project.

The opened file is different from the source file that is used to generate the .dll lib, which is added as a reference to my project. But, I do not know how to solve the problem.

The definition of class MyDataLoad is different from what I see in the source file that is used to generate the .dll file. This is the reason why my c# program in my project cannot call MyLoadDataFile() because it is defined in the source file that is used to generate the .dll file. The definition of class MyDataLoad is different from the files that are used to get .dll file.

Thanks

Comment: @T.S., the class is defined in a namespace. This is the only one class in the .cs file.

Comment: I have no doubts that it is in the namespace. Can you post your code so we see what you have, before and after?

Comment: Ok, I see the definition. Now, what do you see in your c# project when you trying to use your `MyName.MyDataLoad`?

Comment: @T.S., I get this in VS2012, 'MyName.MyDataLoad' does not contain a definition for 'MyLoadDataFile' , are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: See my answer below. It is exactly what I thought

Comment: @T.S., No. The definition of MyLoadDataFile() noes not exist in the .cs file where class MyDataLoad is defined. I open the file by right-clicking MyLoadDataFile() in my project. The opened file is different from the source file that is sued to generate the .dll lib, which is added as a reference to my project. T see that, But, I do not know how to solve the problem. Thanks

Comment: I feel that you don't explain it right. For example, "The definition of MyLoadDataFile() noes not exist ... I open the file by right-clicking MyLoadDataFile()..." This just doesn't make sense. May be you should provide screen shots.

Comment: @T.S., I have added more update.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you have a source file, which was used to build the dll. And you also have another source file, which is in your project. And the file in your project is the same file but contains less code. Is this correct?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46682/discussion-between-user2420472-and-t-s)

Comment: @T.S. , I have a source file, which was used to build the dll. I got the another source file, which was generated by right-clicking the MyLoadDataFile() in VS 2012. The system generated a temporary file that contains the definition of class MyDataLoad. But, it has no MyLoadDataFile() and also other funtions definitions are also missing or different. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that what you referring to is the fact that you can't see method `MyLoadDataFile` in your c# app. This is because you didn't use access modifier. You have

```
void MyLoadDataFile()
```

You need

```
public void MyLoadDataFile()
```

Your default modifier is `private` on class members. And this is why you don't see it